Checking if a polynomial is odd or even
I am reading a paper: 'Center of mass distribution of the Jacobi unitary ensembles: Painleve V, asymptotic expansions' by Zhan, Blower, Chen, Zhu.
On page 14 we have a differential equation (4.29) for a polynomial $C_{n}(\lambda)$:
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{2}[C_{n}''-2(C_{n}'')^{2}]=8\lambda(C_{n}')^{3}-8C_{n}(C_{n}')^{2}-(8n^{2}+7\lambda^{2})(C_{n}')^{2}+\left(6n^{2}\lambda+\frac{3\lambda^{3}}{2}\right)C_{n}'+8\lambda C_{n}C_{n}'-2C_{n}^2-\left(2n^{2}+\lambda^{2}\right)C_{n}-\frac{3\lambda^{4}}{32}-\left(\frac{3n^{2}}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\right)\lambda^{2}
\end{equation}
Now the authors say that if $\widehat{C}_{n}(\lambda):=C_{n}(-\lambda)$ then $\widehat{C}_{n}(\lambda)$ also satisfies (4.29) and an outcome of this is that $C_{n}(\lambda)$ is even in $\lambda$.
How do I check that $\widehat{C}_{n}(\lambda)$ satisfies (4.29)? How do we know that $C_{n}(\lambda)=C_{n}(-\lambda)$, which is what we mean by even functions. What if there had been cubic terms in $\lambda$ at the end of the right hand side, would $C_{n}(\lambda)$ still be even?
Thanks in advance.

Even derivatives of $\hat{C}(-\lambda)$ erase the minus sign and odd powers of $\lambda$ are paired with odd derivatives. The chain rule gives the result. For example $(-\lambda)^3[\hat{C}(-\lambda)]'=\lambda^3\hat{C}'(-\lambda)$

The primes denote derivatives with respect to $\lambda$ only, right? I am not sure if I get your comment fully. Could you please elaborate.

Nevermind, I got it, thanks for the help.
